# Can't get UIBezierPath to apply linecapstyle / linejoinstyle

Tags: ios, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I'm trying to draw a chevron shape inside my UIView subclass. The chevron appears, but the line cap style and line join styles that I'm applying aren't being reflected in the output.

```
 - (UIBezierPath *)chevron:(CGRect)frame
{
    UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [[UIBezierPath alloc]init];
    [bezierPath setLineJoinStyle:kCGLineJoinRound];
    [bezierPath setLineCapStyle:kCGLineCapRound];
    [bezierPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame), CGRectGetMaxY(frame))];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(frame), CGRectGetMaxY(frame) * 0.5)];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame))];

    return bezierPath;
}
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    [self.color setStroke];
    UIBezierPath *chevronPath = [self chevron:rect];
    [chevronPath setLineWidth:self.strokeWidth];
    [chevronPath stroke];
}
```

According to Apple's docs, they say that "After configuring the geometry and attributes of a Bezier path, you draw the path in the current graphics context using the stroke and fill methods" but that isn't working here —-- I've tried moving the `setLineJoinStyle` and `setLineCapStyle` statements around (e.g., after adding LineToPoint, inside drawRect) and it seems like no matter how many times I call them it isn't working. Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is applying those styles, you just can't see them because your chevron is being drawn all the way to the edge of your view then getting clipped. To see the ends of your chevron, change your call to the chevron method to this,

```
UIBezierPath *chevronPath = [self chevron:CGRectInset(rect, 10, 10)];
```

Whether 10 points is enough of an inset will depend on how wide your line is, so you may need to increase that.